# Bounding long-range dependencies in the Contact Process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider the supercritical contact process on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ with infection rate $q/4$ and recovery rate $1-q$ and its space-time-diagram $\mathbb{Z}^2 \times (-\infty, 0]$. Let $\mathbb{P}_{q}$ denote the probability measure wrt to the underlying Poisson processes. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $w \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ let

\begin{align*}
\eta^{(n)}_w := \textbf{1}[\exists (v,t) \text{ with } ||v-w||_\infty = \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor \text{ or } t = -\sqrt{n} : (v,t) \rightarrow (w, 0)]
\end{align*}

and write $\eta^{(n)}_\Lambda$ for the joint distribution of the $\lbrace \eta^{(n)}_w \rbrace_{w \in \Lambda}$, $\Lambda \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^2$.

Now fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $b \in \lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace$ and $\Lambda = [-R,R]^2$ for some $R \in \mathbb{Z}$ and let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ be large enough such that $k \geq R+\sqrt{n}$.
Dissect the subset $[-k, k]^2 \times [-k, 0]$ of the space-time-diagram canonically into stripes of length $2^{-k}$.
Consider Bernoulli variables $X_1, \dots, X_K$, $K \in \mathbb{N}$ given, being $1$ either if there is a Poisson point indicating an arrow in some stripe $s_i$ or if there is no Poisson point indicating a star in $s_i$ (wlog assume each $s_i$ is on a time axis corresponding to some $v \in \Lambda$).

Further, consider the event $A := \lbrace \eta^{(n)}_\Lambda \in A' \rbrace$, $A' \subseteq \lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace ^{\Lambda}$ - for example some kind of crossing. Abbreviate $\lbrace X = b \rbrace = \lbrace X_1= \dots= X_K =b \rbrace$.

How can I bound $|\mathbb{P}_{q}(A)-\mathbb{P}_{q}(A \mid X=b)|$?

Intuitively, the influence of these few stripes should not matter, so I am quite optimistic this can be done. However, my only idea is to introduce the event

\begin{align}
B &= \lbrace \text{the state of } \Lambda \text{ is independent of the Poisson points in} \cup_{i=1}^K s_i \rbrace \\
&= \lbrace \omega \in \Omega \mid \forall \omega' \in \Omega \text{ with } \omega \setminus \cup_{i=1}^K s_i = \omega' \setminus \cup_{i=1}^K s_i : \eta_\Lambda^{(n)}(\omega) =  \eta_\Lambda^{(n)}(\omega') \rbrace
\end{align}

because then $A \cap B$ and $\lbrace X = b \rbrace$ are independent implying

\begin{align}
|\mathbb{P}_{q}(A)-\mathbb{P}_{q}(A \mid X=b)| &= |\mathbb{P}_{q}(A \cap B^c)-\mathbb{P}_{q}(A \cap B^c \mid X=b)| \\
&\leq \mathbb{P}_{q}(X=b)^{-1}|\mathbb{P}_{q}(A \cap B^c)\mathbb{P}_{q}(X=b)-\mathbb{P}_{q}(A \cap B^c)| \\
&\leq \mathbb{P}_{q}(X=b)^{-1}2\mathbb{P}_{q}(B^c) ,
\end{align}

which is rather unclear to me.

Remark: For my purposes it suffices to consider an up-set $A'$ resp. increasing $A$, in which case one could change $=$ to $\leq$ in the definition of $B$ - such that the state of each $1$ is independent of ... .
Remark 2: I am trying to apply the ideas given in the paper of Tobias Müller on confetti percolation (2015/17) to the contact process.

Comment: (1) It seems to me that some terminologies are not fully explained (such as how the arrow/star-decorated Poisson point process is related to the contact process, how each $X_i$ is defined, and what is $b$, etc...). (2) This seems to deserve attention from research-level colleagues, which means that MathOverflow may suit better for your question.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! $b$ can be $0$ or $1$, and there are two types of $X_i$ - one are of the kind "$1$ if there is an arrow", the others are "$1$ if there is no star".

Comment: (3) The question is really interesting, however. Anyway, given that the proof is mentioning Voronoi percolation, I humbly guess that the [*recent technology*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07978) developed for Voronoi percolation might be a good read as well. (It is quite short!) It also involves the technique of 'tensorizing' the Poisson point process and a version of noise sensitivity argument using randomized algorithm. (p.s. It seems that such direction has already been studied for confetti percolation itself, see [*this*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.03307).